# Define command that can only be used in the preamble

Tags: macros, preamble

I remember there was a LaTeX macro used internally to define commands that can only be used in the preamble, but I cannot remember its name nor look it up.

Which is that command, and how is it used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `\@onlypreamble`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ACommand{\def\Example{}}

\makeatletter
\@onlypreamble\ACommand
\makeatother

\ACommand % ok

\begin{document}

\ACommand % error

\end{document}
```

output:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \ACommand
               % error
?
```